# When should a Reference be used and when should a ProjectReference be used

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reference

I believe i fully understand the difference between the two.

A *Reference* simply points to a certain assembly that is used (whether a full path is specified, or it is looked up in the GAC).

A *ProjectReferences* assumes the referenced project resides in the same VS solution as the referencing project, and uses the project GUID to determine which project should be referenced.

The benefit of having a *ProjectReference* is that Visual Studio can detect the dependencies and rebuild them if necessary (if i reference project A and it's not built, it will be rebuilt). Moreover, the referenced project output will be taken (based on the current active configuration, etc).

This drove us to strive and go for an "All ProjectReference" approach.

My problem is this leads to solution files where many dependency projects are included. If dependencies themselves have references assemblies, these would be added as ProjectReferences, forcing these to be ever built by the same .sln file, and not be independent.

My question is -- In what case should ProjectReferences be used without any question? and in what case should they be absolutely avoided? (if ever)

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing the code for the referenced project, then that's when it's ideal to use a project reference.  However, if you purchase a third party control (Telerik RadControls for example) those you would likely just reference the DLL (Reference).

If you don't need to compile it, change version #, etc.  Just use a reference.

Also, it doesn't compile the project reference every time.  Only if it sees that code has changed or a few other things that cause it to trigger (like a full rebuild, or certain changes in it's own references).

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing modifications on theses references and need to recompile it's better to keep Project References, but if the dependecies development is done, compile it as release, register them to GAC and use Assembly References to speedup your compilation time!

Comment: The references projects are also under development. The question is should i keep all of them as project references or not. This leads to coupling between project(s) and a solution file. What other alternatives do i have instead of this...

Comment: You could possibly set up a build system (CC.NET for example) that would compile the project or recognize a change in the directory, copy the DLL to a location that is known by both solutions and use that as the reference.  But it's a bit complex and much easier to just use the project reference IMHO.